# importing headers when compiling for osx & ios

Tags: ios, xcode4, static-libraries, workspace

Say i have two libraries "Foo" and "Bar", compiling as frameworks for OSX and static libraries for IOS.

Library 'Foo' depends on library 'Bar'. I'm using XCode4 workspaces.

In Ascii-art:-

- **IOS_App**
- ~ Foo.a
- ~ ~ Bar.a

and

- **OSX_App**
- ~ Foo.framework
- ~ ~ Bar.framework

Must file **Foo.m** that #imports **Bar.h** look like this:-

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
  #import "Bar.h"
#else
  #import <Bar/Bar.h>
#endif
```

Or, is there a way, maybe by copying headers when building **Bar**, and setting Search Paths appropriately, to make

```
  #import <Bar/Bar.h>
```

work in both cases?

*(I suppose the root of my problem is not properly understanding the difference between `#import </>` and `#import ""`)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this sort of thing extensively, and what I ended up doing was modifying the prefix header for the application/project to import either the specific header file for the library/framework or if the prefix is common between OS X and iOS (such as for the Foo library/framework) adopt the first example in your question.

Then in Foo.m you don't need to have any #import statements at the top.

So, for example, in the prefix header for Foo.framework have

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
  #import "Bar.h"
#else
  #import <Bar/Bar.h>
#endif
```

and in the prefix header for your Mac OS X application have

```
#import <Foo/Foo.h>
```

and for iOS

```
#import "Foo.h"
```

Then all you source code, doesn't need to worry about the headers for any of the classes in your common libraries/frameworks.

Comment: That could work, thanks for the answer. I have a feeling that although i've always supposed `#import <Foo/Foo.h>` meant "import Foo.h from Foo.framework" this isn't the whole story, and it could work for static libraries.

Comment: No worries. Traditionally, using the #import <> style is to indicate to the OS that this header can be found in the system somewhere, such as in ~/Library/Frameworks, where you might install them on the Mac. Whereas the #import "" style means that this header is in the application itself, which is the case on iOS where you can't install libraries outside your sandbox.

Comment: exactly, if "indicate to the OS that this header can be found in the system somewhere" actually means "Look in the Header Search Paths" then modifying the Header Search Paths would be a much better solution than #if TARGET_OS_IPHONE #else #endif

Comment: @fakeAccount22 right, you'd think so, except that on iOS you can't have dynamic libraries, the final build stage links the libraries into the final binary, so there isn't a ../Frameworks/ folder as there is on Mac OS X.